# how to continuously increment student number after click save with key event

Tags: java

I am making an enrollment System which can generate a student number which starts at 1000000. Once saved it will continously increase by a value of 1 which the second student number will look like this '1000001'.

The increase of student number should happen after clicking save. I am using key event, after the user click ENTER the system will check if there's a match of student number. If there's a match the number will increment by 1, but unfortunately after pressing ENTER for generating new student number nothing happen. Please see the code below.

Note: The first Key Release works, only after saving and click the the key release again for generating new student number, it doesn't work anymore.

```
public class generate_stud_num {

    public void create() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sca");
            Statement stmnt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmnt
                    .executeQuery("SELECT Student_Number FROM student_form_new 
                                   order by Student_Number ASC");
            while (rs.next()) {
                // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                // "Student Number already exist");
                studID = rs.getInt("Student_Number");
                studID += 1;
                INC = Integer.toString(studID);
                // System.out.println(INC);
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception er) {
            er.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// close method

}// close class
```

Here is the code for key event.

```
public class Mylistener implements KeyListener {

    generate_stud_num gsn = new generate_stud_num();

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == textStudentID) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                gsn.create();
                textStudentID.setText(gsn.INC);
            }
        }
    }// end method

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO: Do something for the keyTyped event
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO: Do something for the keyPressed event
    }

}// close inner class
```

Comment: When you say it doesnt work anymore does that mean you get an error and it stops or the incrementing stops?

Comment: Why not just set an auto-increment, primary key `student_number` for your students table?

Comment: the best way is don't use key event. key event didn't confirmed that new student has been added.

Comment: Actualy it doesnt get an error, but i was expecting after I press enter again it should generate new student number, but nothing happen.

Comment: As by Mr. Rafa El, don't use key-event, rather than this use onClick event and in your logic check if enrollment no. is already available or not if it is available, update/store for same other-wise increment it by 1.

Comment: Yes i'm aware that key event didn't confirmed that new student has been added, but i have a class that checks whether that student number already exist or not by using query, and it works on the first attempt but after i click save and press ENTER for generating new student number, thats the time the program doens't work anymore.

Comment: You can add a unique constraint over student_number column to avoid duplicates and set auto Increment for that column.

Comment: you mean the key event code didn't execute or `studID+=1` didn't performed?

Comment: Yes Rafa El. after pressing ENTER the studID+=1 must be executed in order for the student number to increase. but after I press ENTER nothing happen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Actualy it doesnt get an error, but i was expecting after I press enter again it should generate new student number, but nothing happen"*

I think what's happening is that everytime the key is pressed, you are creating a new `generate_stud_num` object. If `INC` in that class is not `static` it won't increment on every instantiation. Your variable `INC` should be `static`

```
public static int INC;
```

Also, instead of using a `KeyListener`, you may want to look into using key bindings instead. And I'm not sure what the `KeyListener` is registered to, But maybe you want to use a button instead an add an `ActionListener` that performs your desired action.

Also, as I commented, you may want to look into using an auto-increment primary key of student_number for your database table. Every time a new student is added, the student_number will auto-increment.

---

Also, for better help sooner, learn to post an [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I made a few test of my code regarding this issue and I found out that the key press work only after I make any actions in combo boxes or textfields in student form. Once I input text then i press ENTER it will generate student number, but if I press ENTER first withuot touching the textfields or combo boxes, nothing happen. Can you help me with this? thanks

Comment: You have not provided enough code for me to help you with this prolem. You should a sk another questrion. Try making it clear and with more code

Comment: What I need is to hilight the cursor in any of the textfield or comboboxes in the form (i.e. Last Name). I found out that after I click save the cursor looses  its focus, thats why I need to click manualy in any of the text field before the key press work.

Comment: _Don't_ use KeyListener on TextFields. Can you paint a clearer picture of what exactly you wish to accomplish. Also instead of having the action the being performed on a text field, why not have a submit button, that will gather all of the data from all the fields and the combo box together? It makes more sense

Comment: I think it has something to do with the requestFocus(); method. In order for the cursor to focus on the desired textfield after clicking save. As what I have said the cursor looses its focus for the reason the key press could not work, only if i click the cursor in the textfield, thats the time the key press will work.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense. You can't expect it to work without focus. Also, like I said, don't use a KeyListener on a text field. If all you want is the action to perform when you hit eneter, then use an ActionListener. That's what its made for. When you hit enter on the text field, the action will perform

Comment: Yes I'll try adding key binding.. By the way thanks for your help.